# Flexible height with dynamic layout in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, layout, interface-builder, osx-lion

I'm new to the Dynamic Layout concept introduced in Cocoa applications with Lion 10.7.

I've been playing with some examples and almost all works as I expect. But, there is one thing I've been unable to get: Flexible Height in some elements.

I have one NSTextField element where I can set properly the following constraints:

- Leading to trailing -> To keep it "near" to left and right border resizing its width.
- Vertical space -> To keep it "near" to the previous vertical element.

I also set:

- Vertical space -> To keep it "near" to the bottom border.
- Height >= x -> With the previous one, to make its height "flexible" and adjustable to the view's height when resized.

When I test it, it works in the "horizontal axis" (location and size) but it doesn't allow me to resize the window's height (it's fixed).

If I delete the "Vertical space" constraint that attaches the NSInputText to the view's bottom, I can resize the window but the NSInpuntText's height remains unchanged.

Another annoying thing is that the "default" height constraint for the NSInputText (that on "pink" color) can't be deleted or modified. Whenever I do that a new one is created.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

If I use a "Text View" (NSScrollView with a NSTextField inside) instead of a "plain" NSTextField I'm able to create the behavior I want with any problem.